# Move cursor x lines from current position in vi/vim

Tags: vim, vi

Is there a way to move the cursor a relative amount of lines in vi/vim? Say you have the cursor 10 lines under a block of code you want to remove. If you have the line numbers shown in relative order, it would be nice to have a "jump 10 lines up command" that would take you there.

Or perhaps it's better to have the absolute line numbers shown and go xgg where x is the line number?

Comment: If you have to repeat it multiple times: https://superuser.com/questions/429917/repeat-last-normal-mode-command-including-moves-in-vim

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Yep, of course there's a way. `j` and `k` move down and up one line, so `10j` and `10k` move down and up ten lines. You can repeat any motion by putting a number before it.

You might also want to `set relativenumber` if this is something you do a lot of - it'll help save you counting by printing line numbers relative to the current line, instead of absolute numbers.

Comment: Thanks! I should have figured out the count would apply to the move commands too. You made my day!

Comment: Since Vim 7.4 it's possible to see both relative and absolute line numbers at the same time by adding the following to .vimrc `set relativenumber` and `set number`. This will give relative line numbers with an absolute line number for the line your cursor is on.

Comment: You can also move down a number of lines by simply typing the number followed by `enter` (for absolute line numbers, just preface it with a colon). If you're used to `j` and `k` and a normal keyboard layout, that may not be too helpful, but as an arrow-using Colemak user, `enter` is easier to reach than the Colemak `j` (the QWERTY `y` key )

Answer (score 56):

Moving 10 lines up and down might not suit your task as well as other options. Consider other movements:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> page forward and back.

<kbd>}</kbd>, <kbd>{</kbd> move forward and back by one paragraph.

You can write rules in your vimrc to bind `10j` to a key, say `J` to move down 10 lines by adding the following line to your vimrc file:
`map <S-j> 10j`

However you'd be overwriting the useful existing `J` command (join two lines). Finding a well positioned unused key combination for `10j`/`10k` might be difficult, so I suggest using the existing movements that I mentioned.

You may also want to know that you can move backwards to a word that you see by doing:
`?someword` and forward to a word you see by doing `/someword`. These are going to be faster than trying to move up/down 10 lines and then repositioning your cursor to the exact location. If you cant think of a simple search string for the line in question, you can always go to the line number as you said (`xgg`).

Comment: Page up and down accomplished what I was looking for!

Comment: I use ctrl-f and ctrl-b all the time but overlooked {,} which are maybe the best granularity for editing code!  Thanks!

Comment: Knowing exactly how many lines one needs to move is close to impossible. { and } are my preferred option.

Answer (score 16):

I was messing with vim and I noticed <kbd>-</kbd> moves you up and <kbd>+</kbd> moves you down, so you can:

```
10-
```

or you could use <kbd>k</kbd> since you're most likely used to <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>k<kbd>l</kbd> cursor movement.

Comment: For moving forwards, `enter` works the same as `+` after a number, and is easier to reach most of the time

Comment: @SnoringFrog Yeah, but this is just so there can be some relationship between up and down; I don't mean for anyone to actually move up and down like this, because hjkl would be the fastest anyway.

Comment: tiny addition when testing this locally:
10j and 10+ aren't identical: 10j keeps the column number, whereas 10+ goes to the first non whitespace character on that line, starting column agnostic